# How can I create a wifi hotspot and share my localhost across

Tags: manjaro, wlan, wifi-hotspot

I know how to make a wifi hotspot on my linux machine(using Manjaro with i3 DE), also I managed to connect my iPhone to the wifi connection I made, but the goal is to start lampp and make my iPhone and other devices, like another PC, a smart TV have access to my localhost server.

Is it possible to make this even without an Internet connection? Like without my wifi router on, or without any ethernet? I guess you could say that is somehow a fake hotspot without access to the outer world :D

Basically I need something like a wifi lan, so if anybody could suggest some ideas, software or some tutorials/documentation on net, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, actually it worked by itself :D 
I had to create the hotspot via NetworkManager, and then start lampp, or the other way, the order doesn't matter.

The problem was that I tried to access localhost, instead of the my IP :D
So after I tried to access my IP, it worked as desired. Sorry for wasting your time, I was just a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible. You can host some content using apache and with appropriate apache and firewall rules that allows incoming connections from your other devices. You can use any device to access the server that is connected to the network directly through wifi or ethernet. (i.e you don't need internet).

Once you successfully launch an apache server listening on a specific port (default port is 80), you can use for example an iPhone browser to access your apache server at `ip:port` where `ip` would be the local ip address of the computer where the server is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to (literally) use your Linux machine as an access point, using a WiFi adapter installed on it, you need to look up tutorials on `hostapd`. Note that relatively few adapters are compatible and can be used as access points.

There are various different software packages to set up captive portals, or you could create your own with `iptables` rules and `apache`.